# Update model from directive from $apply or $digest cycle in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I try update model from directive and have some trouble when $apply or $digest already in progress. And I have some questions:

1. Why `scope[attrs.ngModel]` is exist, but `ngModel.$modelValue` isn't
   exist in $apply phase?
2. Why view can be not always updated in $digest phase (especially in difficult situations)?
3. Is $digest phase local $digest() or $root.$digest() (from $apply()) in my example?

```js
require: '?ngModel',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

  element.bind('myEvent', function(e) {        
    //Update model from directive in phase:               $apply  |  $digest

    scope[attrs.ngModel].value = scope.$$phase; //Model: '$apply' | '$digest'
    //or
    ngModel.$modelValue.value  = scope.$$phase; //Model: 'none'   | '$digest'
    //or
    ngModel.$modelValue.value  = scope.$$phase; //Model: ''       | '$digest'
    ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$modelValue);
  });
}
```

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/gVY6GJejEKCLdTIXNAzK?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Thats because angular does'nt know how to map the model to your DIV element. angular has builtin model implementations for almost any INPUT (except INPUT type file), SELECT and TEXTAREA element. 
   In your case (a DIV with a applied ng-model) there is no matching model adapter known to angular. what property/attribute of the DIV element should take angular to be in sync with your model ?? thats why ou have no $modelValue applied.
   what you have to do is to provide a custom model adapter to angular OR you need to use a INPUT, SELECT or TEXTAREA element.
2. because in $digest phase angular assumes all changes are done.
3. there is no local or global $digest phase. phases are always associated to your ng-app.

Comment: How I can create and provide a custom model adapter? Or advise please suitable article.

How I can change model in $digest phase if angular assumes all changes are done? Now I use scope.$$phase || scope.$apply, but it is a bad way, I think...

Comment: I am really sure your code example and question does'nt reflect your real problem. what you do in your code is ... almost wrong, anyway what you want to do and i am sorry to say that, really :-) if you want to keep your code "as is" the only choice you have is to check current phase and in case it is NOT "$apply" : wrap your value setter within scope.$apply( function() { scope[attrs.ngModel].value = "whatever you want"; }) to restart applying a new value. But as i said - you should rethink your example code to show what you *REALLY want*.